# Connecting to other machine in LAN MongoDB using IP

Tags: mongodb

I know that my question is somewhere similar to few other questions of its type but couldn't find the answers posted for that useful to me. So Im posting it again.

I tried bind_ip as follows to make mongo instance listen to other machines in a LAN
[image]

But when Trying to connect in the shell like

[image]

The two systems are connected through LAN. Please answer this in all possible scenarios.

Comment: Sorry but are you actually asking that you have mongo running on one machine and now you want to connect to mongo on another machine where it is not actually running? So not just connect **from** one machine to another, but you expect a connection **to** the machine where it is not running?

Comment: The connection attempt using mongo.exe  is actually done from other machine. Does any administrator privileges come into picture ? Is there any thing other than this to check? @ Blakes Seven

Comment: I just want to be clear that `mongod` ( the server ) is running on the machine with the IP that you are trying to connect to. Which makes this no different to any other question in that you have either 1. Not actually running 2. Wrong IP address of target 3. Firewall rules blocking external access.

Comment: Blakes Seven . I really don't understand what you meant to say . I started mongod on machine A using bind_ip  0.0.0.0 , which actually make mongod listen no restricted. From machine B i'm trying to connect mongod on A using A's Ip and default port. I also tried connecting with Robomongo but I was unlucky. I was successful in connecting to my other friend machine C doing thhe same. Dont understand why it fails in the A, B case.

Comment: It's quite simple. 1, Is it running? Then if so okay. 2. Are you certain you have the correct IP and that is reachable. Ping etc. If so then okay. Which leaves 3. which being windows has more than likely a firewall rule that needs to be configured to allow access from external adresses. So that is either windows firewall or one installed with whatever AV protection you are using. These are the networking 101 problems. Also `--bind_ip` is not required since this happens by default.

Comment: Added mongod.exe in firewall apps . Now working perfectly fine. Tnq @Blakes Seven

Answer (score 0):

Added mongod.exe to list of firewall apps and that is working fine.